# Failing to show an individual entry from an API in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building my first little AngularJS app.

I'm successfully able to show all entries from the API on the home page of the app.

Then I'm routing the user via `ng-href` to `/jobs/{{job.id}}` and have the appropriate controller to do that.

My console.log statement is telling me that the correct entry is being loaded via the `GET` request method but the template isn't actually pulling that back for display.

Here's the extent of what I have so far http://plnkr.co/QPW3lsLHfPxyYOKcVOKY (obviously my API isn't public) but wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing in my show template relating to the showController perhaps?

I've been working along with CodeSchool but I've had to make some mods to their code (for example the showController wasn't correctly defining $http or $routeParams).

Help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot jobs.json files in your demo.

Comment: Didn't forget, just didn't want to dump the entire API output. I've now added jobs.json with 2 entries and jobs/988.json which mocks the single endpoint.

Comment: So, it's getting the data and just not displaying?

Comment: Yeah, console.log statement giving me what I expect. The route is loading the right template but yeah, no data displayed.

Comment: have you tried `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: Haven't gotten as far as setting scope just yet. Was under the impression this should work without doing anything like that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there's an issue between the tutorial version of Angular 1.3.x and the one I'm using 1.4.x

However, using this works as sweet as a nut, passing $scope as a function parameter

```
angular.module('JobStore')
.controller('JobsShowController', function($http, $routeParams, $scope) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/jobs/' + $routeParams.id + '.json'
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.job = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```